# TSQL: How to get distinct values over a period of time but not within my group by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sum, distinct

I'm not sure if the title fits but what i'm trying to do is create an aggregate table with stats broken down by **hour** but i need the distinct values over a period of time not by that hour.  example:

```
ID  Group  Date 
-------------------------
1     1    1/1/2014 11:00
2     1    1/1/2014 11:00
1     1    1/1/2014 11:00
3     1    1/1/2014 11:00
3     2    1/1/2014 12:00
1     2    1/1/2014 12:00
1     1    1/1/2014 12:00
2     1    1/1/2014 12:00
4     1    1/1/2014 12:00
```

The result would be:

```
Count    Group    Hour
------------------------
  3        1      11:00
  2        2      12:00
  1        1      12:00
```

Notice how the ID of 1 shows up multiple times within group 1 but but is only counted once over multiple hours but is grouped by hour.  My problem is i get unique with that hour but if another 1 happens in another hour its counted.

This is my query:

```
MERGE dbo.tblStatsHourlyDomainCampaign AS Target
USING (SELECT   
          (LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,sl.CreateDate,120),13) + ':00') as ReportDay, 
          em.DomainID, COUNT(distinct sl.EmailID) as Opens, sl.QueueID 
       FROM dbo.tblEmail em 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblImpressionLog sl ON em.EmailID = sl.EmailID
       WHERE sl.CreateDate >= '10/1/2014' AND sl.CreateDate < '10/10/2014'
       GROUP BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,sl.CreateDate,120),13) + ':00', em.DomainID , sl.QueueID) AS Source 
    ON (target.domainid = source.domainid AND target.ReportDay = source.ReportDay 
        AND target.QueueID = source.QueueID)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND source.DomainID IS NOT NULL
  THEN 
    INSERT (DomainID, ReportDay, Opens, QueueID) 
    VALUES (source.DomainID, source.ReportDay, source.Opens, source.QueueID)

WHEN MATCHED
  THEN 
    UPDATE 
       SET target.Opens = source.Opens;
```

Comment: please update the sample data column names to what is exactly used in query.
If i get it correct, u just need to remove one column from groupby

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Count(1),
       [group],
       cast(date as time)
FROM  (SELECT Row_number()
                OVER (
                  partition BY id, [group]
                  ORDER BY id, date, [group]) row_num,
              id,
              [group],
              date
       FROM   #temp) a
WHERE  row_num = 1
GROUP  BY [group],
          date
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your example data and result, you could filter ids with row_number partitioned by group. Let the id only exists in the first hour in one group.

```
with t1 as
(
select row_number() over (partition by id, [group]  order by createdate) as rowid
       ,id, [group], createdate
from your_table
)
select count(*),[group],left(convert(VARCHAR,createdate,120),13)
from t1
where rowid=1
group by [group],left(convert(VARCHAR,createdate,120),13)
```

See [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d44248/4/0)